# POST parameters in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, request.querystring, querystringparameter

I'm trying to get parameters received from a form, that were sent with method POST.

I don't know how it's called in asp, M$ loves to change stuff's names to mess with us. They come in HTTP body, while GET/QueryString parameters come in URL after the ? sign.

In PHP, "get patameters" are available in the `$_GET` array. In asp they are `Request.QueryString["parameter1"]`.

"post patameters" are in `$_POST`, and I cant find it in asp. I hope I made it clear :p

Comment: I'll try all suggestions tomorrow, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your querystring is something like this :

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions.aspx?id=17844065&title=post-parameters-in-asp-net
```

if i am right then you are looking for this. Please note this is regarding ASP.Net, I have no idea about classic ASP. And this will not work on classic ASP, I believe.

You can use in cs,

```
if(Request["id"]!=null )
{
  var id= Request["id"]; // gives you id as 17844065 string values
}


if(Request["title"]!=null )
{
  var title= Request["title"]; // gives you title as string 
}
```

Update :

```
NameValueCollection nvc = Request.Form;
string userName, password;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nvc["txtUserName"]))
{
  userName = nvc["txtUserName"];
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nvc["txtPassword"]))
{
  password = nvc["txtPassword"];
}
```

Comment: This is about GET parameters. I need POST parameters.

Answer (score 2):

To read the value from `paramater1` contained inside the form data:

```
string paramater1 = Request.Form["paramater1"];
```

Note that if the form doesn't contain your variable, `paramater1` will be `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Try `Request.Params`, it should contain all GET and/or POST parameters, `Request.Form` should contain only form parameters.